# Xcode12.5 - Archive export for `development` failing by `The data couldn’t be read...`

Tags: ios, archive, xcode11, xcodebuild, xcode12

#### Archive Export is failing on Xcode12.5

##### Using Xcode12.5 on Intel macbook. Steps:

- Archive the app for generic devices is successful.
- Upon selecting export and choosing `Development`. Noticing an error when exporting for `developer distribution`. It fails with this error:

`The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.`

From the `standard.log`.

- `ipatool` is returning null and before that some of the gems are resulting in warning.
- Another `require': cannot load such file -- sqlite3 (LoadError)   from` error.

```
2021-06-03 18:31:35 +0000  Running /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool '/var/folders/sq/2zqgtmr51lz0cwr6zkl8mn4h0000gq/T/IDEDistributionOptionThinning.~~~cf1y84' '--json' '/var/folders/sq/2zqgtmr51lz0cwr6zkl8mn4h0000gq/T/ipatool-json-filepath-~~~K0kOZp' '--toolchain' '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr' '--platforms' '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms' '--app-store-tools-build-version' '12E262' '--info' '--no-validate-bitcode'
2021-06-03 18:31:35 +0000  ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [universal.x86_64-darwin20]
2021-06-03 18:31:35 +0000  /Users/John.doe/.gem/ruby/2.6.6/gems/CFPropertyList-3.0.3/lib/cfpropertylist/rbCFPropertyList.rb:83: warning: assigned but unused variable - temp
2021-06-03 18:31:35 +0000  Ignoring ffi-1.14.2 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.14.2
2021-06-03 18:31:35 +0000  Ignoring ffi-1.13.1 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.13.1
2021-06-03 18:31:35 +0000  Ignoring json-2.5.1 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine json --version 2.5.1
2021-06-03 18:31:35 +0000  Ignoring json-2.3.0 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine json --version 2.3.0
2021-06-03 18:31:35 +0000  Ignoring json-1.8.6 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine json --version 1.8.6
2021-06-03 18:31:35 +0000  Ignoring nokogiri-1.10.3 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.10.3
2021-06-03 18:31:35 +0000  /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- sqlite3 (LoadError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:24:in `<main>'
2021-06-03 18:31:35 +0000  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool exited with 1
2021-06-03 18:31:35 +0000  ipatool JSON: (null)
```

##### On Xcode11.6, same steps results in:

```
ipatool failed with an exception: #<CmdSpec::NonZeroExitException: $ /Applications/Xcode11-6.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3 /Applications/Xcode11-6.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/bitcode-build-tool -v -t /Applications/Xcode11-6.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin --sdk /Applications/Xcode11-6.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.6.sdk -o /var/folders/sq/2zqgtmr51lz0cwr6zkl8mn4h0000gq/T/ipatool20210603-58751-ho4zi4/thinned-out/arm64/Payload/NativeSDK.app/Frameworks/NativeSDK.framework/NativeSDK --generate-dsym /var/folders/sq/2zqgtmr51lz0cwr6zkl8mn4h0000gq/T/ipatool20210603-58751-ho4zi4/thinned-out/arm64/Payload/NativeSDK.app/Frameworks/NativeSDK.framework/NativeSDK.dSYM --strip-swift-symbols /var/folders/sq/2zqgtmr51lz0cwr6zkl8mn4h0000gq/T/ipatool20210603-58751-ho4zi4/thinned-in/arm64/Payload/NativeSDK.app/Frameworks/NativeSDK.framework/NativeSDK
Status: pid 59457 exit 1
Stdout:
    SDK path: /Applications/Xcode11-6.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/
```

Comment: Have you figured out how to fix that?